# PayPal IPN on WordPress Site Stopped Working

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

Had this IPN script working fine with no changes until yesterday (early today)... Here are the key bits of core PayPal code which I am hoping someone can review and let me know if any issues?  My Wordpress code appears to work fine on it's own (so I excluded it)... did Paypal change their version again (1.0 to 1.1 to ??) or URL or something?

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
 echo $errstr . ' (' . $errno . ')';
 $mail_From = 'From: IPN@tester.com';
 $mail_To = 'charlwoode@gmail.com';
 $mail_Subject = 'HTTP ERROR';
 $mail_Body = $errstr;//error string from fsockopen
 mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From); 
 $fh = fopen("logipn.txt", 'a');//open file and create if does not exist
 fwrite($fh, "\r\n/////////////////////////////////////////\r\n HTTP ERROR \r\n");//Just for spacing in log file
 fwrite($fh, $errstr);//write data
 fclose($fh);//close file
}
elseif
{
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    $res=trim($res);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
      $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
      $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
      $aid= $_POST['custom'];  
      $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
      $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];         //full amount of payment. payment_gross in US
      $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
      $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];                   //unique transaction id
      $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
      $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
//do stuff
      }
else {
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... my headers were outdated - these worked:

```
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n"; // NEW
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n"; // NEW
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
// OLD VERSION THAT DIDN"T WORK $fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); // NEW CORRECT VERSION
```

Also don't forget to trim!

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
$res=trim($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problems over the last few days and trying to research it on the Paypal site. The sample coding they now provide for IPN looks completely different to that above (which is what I'm using).

I amended one of my IPN pages to the suggestions above (I already had the additional Headers but not the ssl: or 443 port or the trim code).

This morning though all the IPN pages are working again - not just the amended one - so it looks like PayPal have been playing again!

I couldn't find a link on the PayPal site to this coding to see if there are any other changes needed.